# Group By Sum and without Group by sum Amount is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL queries.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PrincipalBalance)
FROM (
    SELECT 
         lt.AccountId,
         SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN TransactionTypeId IN (1)
                     THEN PrincipalPortionAmount
                 ELSE 0
             END) 
         - SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN TransactionTypeId NOT IN (1, 2)
                       THEN PrincipalPortionAmount
                       ELSE 0
               END) AS PrincipalBalance
     FROM 
         program.LoanTransaction lt
     INNER JOIN 
         program.LoanAccount la ON lt.AccountId = la.Id
     WHERE 
         BranchId = 301
         AND TransactionDate <= 20231231000000
         AND la.STATUS <> - 1
     GROUP BY 
         lt.AccountId
     HAVING  
         SUM(Debit - Credit) > 1
) T
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN TransactionTypeId IN (1) 
                       THEN PrincipalPortionAmount 
                   ELSE 0 
               END), 0)
    - ISNULL(SUM(CASE
                     WHEN TransactionTypeId IN (43, 38, 4, 12, 7, 10)
                         THEN PrincipalPortionAmount 
                     ELSE 0 
                 END), 0)
FROM
    program.LoanTransaction  lt
INNER JOIN
    program.LoanAccount la ON lt.AccountId = la.Id
WHERE
    BranchId = 301 
    AND TransactionDate <= 20231231000000 
    AND la.Status <> -1
```

Query #1 result is
 `80773498.0599999`

Query #2 result is
 `81060946.8400006`

But both results should be the same. I don't get it, why the differences? How can I find out what is causing the differences?

Comment: Try removing your `having` clause

Comment: i have added the same having clause in the 2nd query. i am assuming 1st query result is ok. after adding having query in the 2nd query the 2nd query value does not change

Comment: Btw are you familiar with accepting an answer? You don't appear to have accepted any.

Comment: Having without a group by will have different results.

Comment: Then `WHEN` condition in your second `CASE WHEN` is totally different : in query #1, it's `WHEN TransactionTypeId NOT IN (1, 2)`, while in query #2, it's `WHEN TransactionTypeId IN (43, 38, 4, 12, 7, 10)` ....

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking a question here and are not able to find out on your own. That's quite simple: Reduce the data, for example using harder restrictions on the date. Keep on reducing till the two sums don't differ anymore. Then compare your restriction to the last restriction where the amounts were different. In that time range between those two dates, you will find one of those transactions that cause your difference. Then you will see the reason. You don't need help for that, just more effort rather than let other people do your work.

Comment: @marc_s TransactionTypeId NOT IN (1, 2) and TransactionTypeId IN (43, 38, 4, 12, 7, 10) have same data. just wrote differently

Comment: @JonasMetzler i was just looking for ways how to bring the mismatch ones. first one i am getting the data by account id but in 2nd query is the total sum. therefore i was not able to compare those 2 results.

Comment: And you can compare the 2 queries, you remove the group by and see which rows are returned, then compare to the other query. But as I say your `having` clause is screwing it up.

Comment: @DaleK your point is exactly what helped me. with the having clause.

Comment: @DaleK about the transaction type id i wrote that in different ways in those 2 queries. 

Thanks for the suggestion